# How long before a test app expires on iOS and you have to reinstall it via Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Installed Xcode, coded my app and Built it on my iOS device. After a while (around a month) it fails to start, and it has no errors. If I connect it to Xcode and run it again it starts up just fine and continues to run fine.

Is there some kind of time limit after which a built app installed via Xcode doesn't start anymore?

Comment: may be its related to your memory

Comment: The freebie developer route only signs for about a week. Once we paid $100 to Apple, our development builds started working for longer...

Answer (score -1):

No there is no time limit. It might be your in app token or your apis.